# MapStruct specifie sub mapping

Tags: mapstruct

This is my example.

```
public class Company {
    ....
    private String companyName;
    ....
}

public class Employee {
    ....
    private String name;
    ....
}

public class EmployeeDto {
    ....
    private String name;
    private String companyName;
    ....
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EmployeeDtoMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "source1.name")
    @Mapping(target = "companyName", source = "source2.companyName")
    EmployeeDto toDto(Employee source1, Company source2);

    List<EmployeeDto> toDtos(List<Employee> sources, @Context Company source2);

}
```

I want that the method toDtos use toDto to map Employee to EmployeeDto but mapstruct generate a employeeDtoToEmployeeDto method.
How can I fix it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapstruct only allows for selecting submappings based on 1 source and 1 target. Hence the @Context annotation. This will effectively ignore that parameter, only handed it down to submapping..

But.. you can tackle your problem like this..

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EmployeeDtoMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "source1.name")
    EmployeeDto toDto(Employee source1, @Context Company source2);

    @AfterMapping
    default afterToDto(@MappingTarget EmployeeDto target, @Context Company source2) {
       target.setCompanyName( source2.getCompanyName();
    }

    List<EmployeeDto> toDtos(List<Employee> sources, @Context Company source2);

}
```

Note if you have multiple parameters in mapping source2, and you like to use MapStruct for that as well, you can define a new interface method mapping `EmployDTO toDo(Company source)` and call that from your default method.